# How to fix: " invalid literal for int() with base 10:' ' "

Tags: python, python-3.x

Довольно долго пытаюсь решить проблему:

[image]

Тем, что переписывал тот же код, но разными способами. Без результата.

```
s1=int(input())
s2=1
while s1!=0:
    s1=s1+int(input())
    s2=s2+1
    if s1==10:
        print(s2)
    else:
        continue
```

Помогите решить проблему и если не сложно, объясните в чём суть ошибки (Начинающий). Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

PS:
ввод

```
2
9
-2
1
6
6
6
0
```

Comment: Как и где вы вводите ввод и после ввода чего появляется ошибка?

Comment: Ввожу все данные сразу (в консоль ctrl+v)

Comment: Значит внутрь вашего буфера обмена попала пустая строка, копируйте внимательнее

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)))

Comment: Во всяком случае у меня ваш код на ваших входных данных такой ошибки не выдаёт: https://i.imgur.com/Hb9Rr5k.gif

Comment: А что делать если выдаётся такая ошибка? http://rgho.st/7QpmNDzlx

Comment: Для начала рассказать, как её воспроизвести. Если у вас всё работает, совершенно очевидно, что мы не сможем помочь) Ваш текст ошибки означает, что в ввод попала пустая строка. А почему в ввод попала пустая строка — это уже вам виднее :)

Comment: Дело в том, что я прохожу курс по питону и после залива файла с программой мне выдается ошибка, ссылку на которою я дал. Что делать - я не знаю.

Comment: А, вы уже про EOF. Ну если вы внимательно прочитаете свой код, то вы заметите, что переменная `s1` ВСЕГДА больше нуля, следовательно цикл является вечным и программа никогда не завершится ;)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71140/discussion-between-coooler-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s1=int(input())
s2=1
s3=1
while true:
  s3=int(input())
  s1=s1+s3
  s2=s2+1
  if s3 == 0:
    break
  if s1 == 10:
    print(s2)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!